# Word reduction and multiplication rules for forming product and coproduct of monoids and free monoids

Tags: category-theory, products, monoid, coproduct

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$Rules for word reduction for Monoids

$\textbf{(1a)}$  Multiply adjacent pairs with the same $i-$term:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_j=(x_j,i),a_{j+1}=(x_{j+1},i),\ldots,a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,\hat{a}_j=(x_jx_{j+1},i),a_{j+2},\ldots,a_n)$

$\textbf{(1b)}$   Delete identity terms:

$(a_1,\ldots,a_j=(e_j,i_j),\ldots a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n)$

$\textbf{(2)}$ $\textbf{(Definition 2:)}$  The $\textbf{Free monoid on the set X of generators}$ is the set $X^*$ of all finite sequences of elements from $X$ (including the "empty" sequence $\Lambda$ of length $0$) with associative multiplication of $\textbf{concatenation}$

$$\textbf{(3)}\quad (x_1\ldots x_m)\cdot ({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})=(x_1\ldots x_m, {x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})$$

for which $\Lambda$ is clearly the identity:  $\Lambda\cdot w=w=w\cdot \Lambda$ for all $w\in X^*.$  Note that an element $x$ yields a string $(x)$ in $X^*$ of length one.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

Let $X=X_1\times X_2$ and $X'=X_1\sqcup X_2$ and suppose we are given strings, $(x_1\ldots x_m)$ and $({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'}),$ where $(x_1\ldots x_m)\in X_1$ and $({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})\in X_2.$  I want to form either product or coproduct for both monoids and free monoids in the sense of category theory.  I just have few quick questions.  |

$1)$  The word reduction rules $\textbf{(1a)},$ $\textbf{(1b)},$ and multiplication rule $\textbf{(3)}$ can be apply to strings when forming either product or coproduct for both monoids and free monoids.

$2)$ For both monoids and free monoids, when forming their product and coproducts with strings $(x_1\ldots x_m)$ and $(x_1\ldots x_m),$ in the process, can we ever have the cases: $(x_1\ldots x_m)\cdot ({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})\in X=X_1\times X_2$ or $(x_1\ldots x_m)\cdot ({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})\in X'=X_1\sqcup X_2?$

Answer (score 1):

> $1)$  The word reduction rules $\textbf{(1a)},$ $\textbf{(1b)},$ and multiplication rule $\textbf{(3)}$ can be apply to strings when forming either product or coproduct for both monoids and free monoids.

The rules specifically apply to monoid coproducts. The product of monoids doesn't use words at all, just tuples with a componentwise multiplication.

> $2)$ For both monoids and free monoids, when forming their product and coproducts with strings $(x_1\ldots x_m)$ and $(x_1\ldots x_m),$ in the process, can we ever have the cases: $(x_1\ldots x_m)\cdot ({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})\in X=X_1\times X_2$ or $(x_1\ldots x_m)\cdot ({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})\in X'=X_1\sqcup X_2?$

That depends entirely on what "$\cdot$" means. A priori, there is no definition of multiplication of elements of $X_1$ with elements of $X_2$ and neither the definition of product or coproduct defines such a thing. There are natural inclusions $X_i \to X_1 \times X_2$ and $X_i \to X_1 \sqcup X_2$. You could then define $\cdot$ by including each element into a common domain first.

Comment: If rules (1a), (1b) and (3) can be applied to both monoids and free monoids and when constructing coproducts for both.  What is the difference between the two other than the adjective "free" attached to one of them?  I am not clear on what the conceptual distinction I need to keep in mind.

Comment: @Seth I'm not completely sure what your point of confusion is. The definition of the coproduct of monoids here is fully general, so it specializes to the coproduct of free monoids in particular (though you should be aware that being a coproduct is also dependent on what category you're in). The coproduct of monoids (and relately groups) is sometimes called the "free product", so maybe that's what's confusing you. While that's related to free monoids, it's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: I am guessing that a free monoid is a monoid, but a monoid is not necessarily a free monoid.  Am I correct?  If so, and as for why, I don't understand the subtle conceptual distinction.